# using angular ngrx and firestore, the set() method return undefined

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, store, ngrx, angular7

I made a project using Angular 7, Firestore and ngRx.

I'm writing my effects and the **set() method** isnt working properly.

When using the firestore **add() method**, it works fine because I get a DocumentReference (see tap)

*(the tap is only used for testing purpose)*

**service.ts**

```
createProduct(data): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.db.collection('slack').add({
            ...data
        })).pipe(
            tap(a => console.log('create: ', a))
            // here I get back a DocumentReference
        );
 }
```

**effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
    createProduct$ = this.actions$.ofType(productsActions.CREATE_PRODUCT)
        .pipe(
            map((action: productsActions.CreateProduct) => action.payload),
            switchMap((product) => {
                return this.productService.createProduct(product)
                    .pipe(
                        map(_product => new productsActions.CreateProductSuccess(_product)),
                        catchError((err => of(new productsActions.CreateProductFail(err))))
                    );
            })
        );
```

but when using the **set() method**, I get **undefined** (see tap)

**service.ts**

```
updateProduct(data): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.db.doc(`slack/0aMwkyVWF33PF7qDIvKy`).set({
            ...data,
        })).pipe(
            tap(a => console.log('update: ', a))
            // Here I get undefined
        );
}
```

**effects.ts**

```
@Effect()
    updateProduct$ = this.actions$.ofType(productsActions.UPDATE_PRODUCT)
        .pipe(
            map((action: productsActions.UpdateProduct) => action.payload),
            switchMap((product) => {
                return this.productService.updateProduct(product)
                    .pipe(
                        map(_product => new productsActions.UpdateProductSuccess(_product)),
                        catchError((err => of(new productsActions.UpdateProductFail(err))))
                    );
            })
        );
```

So my effect is expeting to get an ID, but he get undefined.

Why this is working for **add()** and not for **set()/update()** ?

here is my project : https://github.com/angulartist/ngrx-firestore-playground/blob/master/src/products/services/products.service.ts

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly `set()` doesn't return a reference to the document. So, in your service once you have completed the `set()`, you can then pipe the stream and perform a map so you can get a reference to the document you performed the `set()` on. Then you can `switchMap()` and `get()` the newly updated document.

```
updateProduct(data): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.db.doc(`slack/0aMwkyVWF33PF7qDIvKy`).set({
            ...data,
        })).pipe(
            map(_ => this.db.doc(`slack/0aMwkyVWF33PF7qDIvKy`)),
            switchMap(docRef => fromPromise(docRef.get())),
            tap(a => console.log('update: ', a))
            // Here I get undefined
        );
}
```